# SQLite statement Sendable

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, async-await, swift-concurrency

I'm writing my own SQLite wrapper in Swift and I was wondering if the SQLite statement can be made `Sendable` or whether it would be better to make it an `actor`.

```
import SQLite

struct Statement: Sendable {
    private(set) var handle: OpaquePointer?

    init(sql: String, connection: OpaquePointer) {
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, sql, -1, &handle, nil)
    }

    public func finalize() {
        guard let handle else { return }
        sqlite3_finalize(handle)
    }
}

// Resulting in
let connection: OpaquePointer = ...
let statement = Statement(sql: "", connection: connection)
statement.finalize()
```

Or using an actor implementation

```
import SQLite3

actor Statement {
    private(set) var handle: OpaquePointer?

    init(sql: String, connection: OpaquePointer) {
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, sql, -1, &handle, nil)
    }

    public func finalize() {
        guard let handle else { return }
        sqlite3_finalize(handle)
    }
}

// Resulting in
let connection: OpaquePointer = ...
let statement = Statement(sql: "", connection: connection)
await statement.finalize()
```

I'm mostly curious as to how `Sendable` affects the `OpaquePointer`, if it does, and whether an `actor` implementation might solve potential issues with the `OpaquePointer`. The SQLite syntax makes me believe it's *pass by reference*, even though I'd assume a statement could or should be made *pass by value*, hence my `struct Statement: Sendable` protocol. I'm just not sure if that will work.

Comment: I confess that I am very surprised/confused that `OpaquePointer` is still `Sendable` because (a) it is a C pointer, clearly a reference type which is obviously not guaranteed to be safe to share across actors; and (b) [SE-0331](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0331-remove-sendable-from-unsafepointer.md) explicitly says that Swift 5.6 removed `Sendable` conformance.

Comment: So, if I read your comment correctly, implementing statement as an actor is the best way to go, right? As that makes the pointer access sequentially, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [`OpaquePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/opaquepointer/) is, by definition, a reference type (as it is a C pointer).

Regarding providing synchronization via an actor, SQLite has three [threading modes](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), and the iOS default is that it is safe to use database connection from multiple threads, but not simultaneously. So, yes, you would want to use an actor.

Comment: An this also applies to an SQLite statement, as it also used the same underlying C pointer principle, correct?

Comment: Yes, and because simultaneous SQLite calls from multiple threads on the same statement would translate to simultaneous calls to the same underlying database connection at the same time.